# Практикум Си

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. У меня завтра экзамен по Си, подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти задачки не на крутые мозги, а на знание основ языка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Тесты](http://www.quizful.net/category/c)
- [Задачки с вики](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85)
- [Задачник для ВУЗ](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcmcstuff.esyr.org%2Fel-net-20111113%2F3rd%2520Semestre%2F%25D0%259F%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BA%2F%25D0%25A0%25D1%2583%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BE-%25D0%25B7%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B0%25D1%2587%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BA%2520%25D0%25BF%25D0%25BE%2520%25D0%25A1.DOC&ei=aOfPUu2pMcjQtAb43oHoDQ&usg=AFQjCNF-pln-Lb1u6Lx8PRzWX4ty6ekyRA&bvm=bv.59026428,d.Yms&cad=rja)
- [Курс в онлайн университете](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/43/43/info)